# Symbol for square bracket with only one horizontal line

Tags: symbols

The way cycles in permutations are written in my country's textbooks (Serbia) is with square brackets [ and ], but with only one horizontal line at the top to denote the beginning of the permutation, and only one horizontal line at the bottom at the end.

Is there a symbol in LaTeX for this? [image: This is what I'm looking for.]

Comment: I didn't know about detexify. This is incredible, thank you very much!

Comment: I would go with `\newcommand{\permcycle}[1]{\lceil #1 \rfloor}` and then use `$\permcycle{1, 2, 3} \permcycle{p, q}$`.

Answer (score 1):

[detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is able to translate handwritten symbols into possible commands (and necessary packages).  In this case, it's top hits look to be `$\lceil$` and `$\rfloor$`.